# Character with Bit/hex confusion in DB2

Tags: sql, db2-400

This works:

```
SELECT TASKT_ID FROM DATA . TASKT WHERE TASK_WEB_IDENTIFIER = CAST ( HEXTORAW ( '0213725501A421D384233E5001' ) AS CHAR ( 26 ) ) ;
```

Since that work I put it into the procedure:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE GET_TASKT_ID_BY_TASK_WEB_IDENTIFIER_C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
SELECT TASKT_ID FROM DATA . TASKT WHERE TASK_WEB_IDENTIFIER = CAST ( HEXTORAW ( P_WEB_IDENTIFIER ) AS CHAR ( 26 ) ) ;

OPEN GET_TASKT_ID_BY_TASK_WEB_IDENTIFIER_C1 ;
END
```

The procedure has the one parameter P_WEB_IDENTIFIER which is a CHAR(26) for bit data with the CCSID 65535

However, when I now call it with the string like so:

```
call PROGRAM . GET_TASKT_ID_BY_TASK_WEB_IDENTIFIER ('0213725501A421D384233E5001');
```

I get back that the argument for VARBINARY_FUNCTION is invalid by length or data type.

Also, this works:

```
call PROGRAM . GET_TASKT_ID_BY_TASK_WEB_IDENTIFIER (CAST('0213725501A421D384233E5001' as char(26)));
```

What Can I do to make sure that string converts with only the string being passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to call the stored procedure?

What version and release of Db2 for i?

In the **Run SQL Scripts** component of IBM ACS or the older Access for Windows, string literals in your statements are treated as varchar.

Thus the `CAST('0213725501A421D384233E5001' as char(26))` makes sense.  What doesn't is the error message.  Normally, you'd get a *procedure not found* error as the Db is looking for a procedure named `PROGRAM.GET_TASKT_ID_BY_TASK_WEB_IDENTIFIER` that takes a varchar parameter and the only thing that exists is a procedure that takes a char(26).

IBM's tools have gotten better at implicitly converting when needed.  But I usually go with an explicit conversion when testing manually (as you've done here).  Or I just make the parms varchar to start.  And convert to character within the procedure if needed.

The char/varchar difference doesn't usually matter to the client code, as it can be specific in it's type definitions.  It's only a factor for interactive tools like ACS that are executing dynamic statements.